# Round up a variable with Shopify Liquid

Tags: css, math, rounding, shopify, liquid

I wish to assign a dummy variable to a math value so I can then take the ceiling.

My current code is:

```
{% if variant.compare_at_price > variant.price %} 
    SAVE {{ variant.compare_at_price | minus:variant.price | times:100 | divided_by:variant.compare_at_price }}%
{% endif %}
```

Output is SAVE 20% (for example, but if it's 19.99 it'll be 19% rather than 20%)

But I want to call:

```
x= {{ variant.compare_at_price | minus:variant.price | times:100 | divided_by:variant.compare_at_price }}%
```

then take `{{ x | ceil }}`

How do I assign `x`?

Comment: In your title, you mean `Liquid`, not `CSS Liquid`.

Answer (score 0):

By using the [`assign`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/variable-tags#assign) variable tag:

```
{% assign x = variant.compare_at_price | minus:variant.price | times:100.0 | divided_by:variant.compare_at_price %}
{% assign x = x | ceil %}
SAVE {{x}}%
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies but I seem to be getting full figures. E.g.

For a $149 item currently on sale for $139, Shopify lists it as 14900 & 13900.

So I get (14900-13900)*100/14900 = 6. (It should be 6.7).

So then when you take the ceil of 6 you get 6.

I think I need to specify the format as a float first?

Comment: The `divided_by` filter rounds down to the nearest integer. You ca use `modulo` to get the remainder.

Comment: How would I use the modulo to get the decimals? I would still need to use the divide function, which leads to the same issue.

Comment: I found the answer...use times:100.0...I forgot to put the .0. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, yeah I added the `100.0` to the answer.